# Widget which pops up imageButton over other widgets/shortcuts

Tags: android

how to program android widget which size is 1*1 and when it's clicked it shows me new imageButton over other widgets and shortcuts

[image]

Let's suppose that the camera app icon is widget I want the imagebutton(White circle with pink lines) to appear like this:
[image]

now is there any option for the widget to do so or should I use custom library or there are funcs in the widget class which can do this job ??
thnx all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the trick using transparent activity to show the views what I want